# Android: Correct way to initialize ViewModel with dependencies, ViewModelProviderFactory

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I have two `ViewModels` that have dependencies on other objects that in turn might have dependencies on `context` (`SettingsDataStore`). Now to keep the `context` out of my ViewModels I am following the `inversion of control` principle.

My code looks something like this:

```kotlin
// MainActivity.kt
private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore(name = "settings")
val newsRepository = NewsRepository()
val newsDetailViewModel = NewsDetailViewModel()

lateinit var newsViewModel: NewsViewModel
lateinit var settingsViewModel: SettingsViewModel


@Composable
fun Navigation() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val settingsDataStore = SettingsDataStore(context.dataStore)

    if (!::settingsViewModel.isInitialized) {
        settingsViewModel = viewModel(initializer = { SettingsViewModel(settingsDataStore) })
    }

    if (!::newsViewModel.isInitialized) {
        newsViewModel =
            viewModel(initializer = { NewsViewModel(newsRepository, settingsDataStore) })
    }
...
```

So as you can see I am creating the `SettingsDataStore` in the composable function because I need access to `context`. Then I am constructing the `ViewModels` with their dependencies. *However, I suspect this kind of injection is faulty because of plenty of reasons -- invalidation of the context and accidental creation of ViewModels if you are not careful comes to mind.*

Therefore, I did some research found this article of the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-factories) recommending the usage of `ViewModelProvider.Factory`. Unfortunately, I did not figure out how to properly create my `NewsViewModel` using a factory:

```
class NewsViewModel(
    private val repo: NewsRepository,
    private val settingsDataStore: SettingsDataStore
) : ViewModel() {

    ...
    
    // Define ViewModel factory in a companion object
    companion object {

        val Factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory = object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            override fun <T : ViewModel> create(
                modelClass: Class<T>,
                extras: CreationExtras
            ): T {
                // Get the Application object from extras
                val application = checkNotNull(extras[ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.APPLICATION_KEY])
                // Create a SavedStateHandle for this ViewModel from extras
                val savedStateHandle = extras.createSavedStateHandle()

                return NewsViewModel(
                    // TODO HOW DO I ACCESS/CREATE THE DEPENDENCIES ??
                ) as T
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is **how do I create my `NewsViewModel` with that factory?** I want to stick to the Android docs and not use some sort of DI framework.

Sorry for the long question but I wanted be detailed because a lot of people following proper MVVM architecture will run into this.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to avoid a DI framework? Why reinvent the wheel? For very simple dependency chains, you can get by without a framework. You have to manually figure out your dependencies and pass them to the factory's constructor. Which means you cannot use your `object.Factory` property pattern like above. Or you can instantiate your dependencies in your Application class's `onCreate()` and access them via a singleton so they can be used in the factory.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Of course a DI approach would make sense in a big project but this is not a big project and would be a little bit excessive. I wish to learn the Jetpack Compose APIs and I think it's reasonable to stick to the documentation for this. 
In said docs they do access their repo in this manner `(application as MyApplication).myRepository` which makes me wonder how they made the `object.Factory` pattern work. They do not provide a link to the entire source code unfortunately.

Comment: That's a third way you can do it (compared to the first two I mentioned). Instead of storing dependencies in a global or `object` property, they store them in a property in the Application subclass. Then, as long as you can easily access the Application instance (which you can in a ViewModel.Factory using `checkNotNull(extras[APPLICATION_KEY])`), you can access those properties even though they aren't global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by using the `ViewModelProvider` helper class in my Jetpack Compose app. If you are still using the classic XML approach have a look at **@Tenfour04**s approach. Also keep in mind that you should consider using a DI framework for bigger projects.
*So anyways, here is how I created my ViewModels properly with their respective dependencies:*

The Factory itself needed to be changed to take the depedencies as arguments in its constructor:

```
    class NewsViewModelFactory(
        private val newsRepository: NewsRepository,
        private val settingsDataStore: SettingsDataStore
    ) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(NewsViewModel::class.java)) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return NewsViewModel(
                    settingsDataStore = settingsDataStore,
                    repo = newsRepository
                ) as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
        }
    }
```

Now we can just call `ViewModelProvider` in the `Composable` function and pass the `viewModelStoreOwner` and concrete factory to obtain the correct `ViewModel`:

```kotlin
newsViewModel = ViewModelProvider(
        viewModelStoreOwner,
        NewsViewModel.NewsViewModelFactory(
            newsRepository, settingsDataStore
        )
    ).get()
```

This will make sure that the `ViewModel` is correctly created. Every subsequent call will return the already created `ViewModel` which exactly what we want.

The complete example looks like this now:

```kotlin
// MainActivity.kt
private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore(name = "settings")
val newsRepository = NewsRepository()
val newsDetailViewModel = NewsDetailViewModel()

lateinit var newsViewModel: NewsViewModel
lateinit var settingsViewModel: SettingsViewModel


@Composable
fun Navigation() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val viewModelStoreOwner = checkNotNull(LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current) {
        "No ViewModelStoreOwner was provided via LocalViewModelStoreOwner"
    }

    val settingsDataStore = SettingsDataStore(context.dataStore)

    settingsViewModel = ViewModelProvider(
        viewModelStoreOwner,
        SettingsViewModel.SettingsViewModelFactory(settingsDataStore)
    ).get()


    newsViewModel = ViewModelProvider(
        viewModelStoreOwner,
        NewsViewModel.NewsViewModelFactory(
            newsRepository, settingsDataStore
        )
    ).get()
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must never call a ViewModel constructor anywhere except in a `ViewModel.Factory`'s `create()` function.

The pattern used in the documentation you linked is to create a custom application class, in this case named `MyApplication`, and creating the dependencies in its `onCreate()` function and storing them in properties in that class. Something like this:

```
class MyApplication: Application() {
    lateinit var myRepository: MyRepository
        private set

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        myRepository = MyRepository(this) // this, because an Application is a Context
    }
}
```

In your manifest's `<application>` block, add `name=".MyApplication"` to tell it what class to use, the same way you do for `<activity>` blocks.

Then in your factory's `create()` function, you can retrieve the application instance using the extras. The application instance is effectively a singleton because the OS instantiates it one time for your process. The class is defined by the manifest's application name property, so it is safe to cast it to the class you set there.

You can use whatever properties of `MyApplication` you like to pass to the ViewModel's constructor.

```
val myApplication = checkNotNull(extras[ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.APPLICATION_KEY]) as MyApplication

return NewsViewModel(
    myApplication.myRepository
) as T
```